# Count item tags from merged rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm trying to count the title tag from a list of RSS feeds.

```
$urls = "http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($urls);
$tags = array();
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
  $children = $item->title;
  foreach ($children as $node) {
    $tags[] = $node->getName();
  }
}
$count= array_count_values($tags);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($count);
```

doing it this way above... it works but what if I had multiple URLs. how can I go about it?

Comment: Well you will have to put some of this code in a loop

Comment: Do you want the count to be all tags from multiple urls? Or a count of tags for each url

Comment: i want it to be all tags from multiple urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the urls in an array and then just foreach around the urls array doing basically what you were already doing

```
$urls = ["http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml","http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml"];

$tags = array();
foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
        $children = $item->title;
        foreach ($children as $node) {
            $tags[] = $node->getName();
        }
    }
}

$count= array_count_values($tags);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($count);
```